# How to change body background image by clicking a button in Angular 4?

Tags: angular

How to change body background-image (in index.html) by click a button in other project?

I have this simple index.html code:

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

And i try to use `[ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': getBackgroundImg() }"` in app.component.html and in app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent {

public getBackgroundImg(){
    return "url(\"http://fureka.loc/artem-girls/bathtub_(474).jpg\") ";
}
}
```

But its work in other components, not in index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `[ngStyle]` in index.html. Maybe try this in your `app.component.ts`:

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

clickMe() {
    this.renderer.setStyle(document.body, 'background-image', this.getBackgroundImg());
}
```

And in your `app.component.html`:

```
<button (click)="clickMe()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: thanks, i add import Renderer2 component, replace , `getBackgroundImg()` to `this.getBackgroundImg()` and add this code and it is work!

Comment: @SurenderMeg I'm glad I could help. Feel free to accept my answer, if it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
[ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': getBackgroundImg() }""
```

please check your double quotes..

[ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': getBackgroundImg() }"

Comment: i check this. it is my error in this question, not in code. and i repeat. this code work in components html, but dont work in index.html

Comment: please check your selector. it should be same as it is mentioned in an index.html page.

Comment: i check selector, but in other answer write tha i can't use[ ngStyle] in index.html

Comment: the project structure of angular is browser will load index.html file first , it will check the selector which matches and load that html. so in your case you need to write your function in app.component.ts and display your image in app.component.html. so automatically it will reflect in index.html. so basically index.html should have your app.component.ts selector.